# Kotlin. How to format decimal number with zero at the end?

Tags: java, kotlin, integer, double, decimalformat

I need to format the number.

I need the following result:

```
3434 -> 3 434

3434.34 -> 3 434.34

3434.3 -> 3 434.30
```

Here is my code:

```
  val formatter = DecimalFormat("#,###,##0.##")
            return formatter.format(value)
```

But I get a result like this:

```
3434 -> 3 434

3434.34 -> 3 434.34

3434.3 -> 3 434.3 // wrong!! expected 3 434.30
```

I need to add zero at the end if there is one digit after the decimal point.

Please help me how I can fix the problem?

Comment: Have a look at my answer. I get the results you want, using some IF logic and String manipulation.

Comment: Hint: DecimalFormat is a java class. This is nothing to do with kotlin. And this class is around since like ever. Everything you can dream of asking about it ... has been asked here before. Many times. Do some research the next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Example:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;
import java.util.*;  

public class AddZeroToOneDigitDecimal{

     public static void main(String []args){
       System.out.println(customFormat(3434));
       System.out.println("----------");
       System.out.println(customFormat(3434.34));
       System.out.println("----------");
       System.out.println(customFormat(3434.3));
     }

     public static String customFormat(double d){

        String result =  formatter.format(d);
        return (result.replace(".00",""));
     }
     
     private static DecimalFormat formatter;
     private static final String DECIMAL_FORMAT = "#,###,##0.00";
     private static DecimalFormatSymbols formatSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.ENGLISH);
    
     static {
         formatSymbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');
         formatSymbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
         formatter = new DecimalFormat(DECIMAL_FORMAT, formatSymbols);
     }
}
```

### Simplified

```
 val formatter = DecimalFormat("#,###,##0.00");
 return formatter.format(value).replace(".00","");
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove last two `#` after `.` and add `00` in place of `##`.

```
val dec = DecimalFormat("#,###,##0.00")
```

Comment: In this case, for the value 4 000, I will receive 4 000.00, but expected 4 000

Comment: @testivanivan That's a different format. You'll have to work out how to determine when you want 2 decimal places and when you want none, and pick a suitable format to use in each case.